# ffmpeg sws_scale YUV420p to RGBA not giving correct scaling result (c++)

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, yuv, rgba

I am trying to scale a decoded YUV420p frame(1018x700) via sws_scale to RGBA, I am saving data to a raw video file and then playing the raw video using ffplay to see the result.

Here is my code:

```
sws_ctx = sws_getContext(video_dec_ctx->width, video_dec_ctx->height,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, video_dec_ctx->width, video_dec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR32, SWS_LANCZOS | SWS_ACCURATE_RND, 0, 0, 0);
ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, yuvframe, got_frame, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Error in decoding"<<std::endl;
        return ret;
    }else{
        //the source and destination heights and widths are the same
        int sourceX = video_dec_ctx->width;
        int sourceY = video_dec_ctx->height;
        int destX = video_dec_ctx->width;
        int destY = video_dec_ctx->height;

        //declare destination frame
        AVFrame avFrameRGB;
        avFrameRGB.linesize[0] = destX * 4;
        avFrameRGB.data[0] = (uint8_t*)malloc(avFrameRGB.linesize[0] * destY);

        //scale the frame to avFrameRGB
        sws_scale(sws_ctx, yuvframe->data, yuvframe->linesize, 0, yuvframe->height, avFrameRGB.data, avFrameRGB.linesize);

        //write to file
        fwrite(avFrameRGB.data[0], 1, video_dst_bufsize, video_dst_file);
 }
```

Here is the result without scaling (i.e. in YUV420p Format)
[image: Here is the result without scaling (i.e. in YUV420p Format)]

Here is the after scaling while playing using ffplay (i.e. in RGBA format)
[image]

I run the ffplay using the following command ('video' is the raw video file)

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr32 -video_size 1018x700 video
```

**What should I fix to make the correct scaling happen to RGB32?**

Comment: The endianness is different - try ffplay with `bgr32`

Comment: Your question text says 1024x76, but your ffplay is 1024x760 - experiment with different Y values and see if you get a correct output. This should help you debug.

Comment: On the face of it, `avFrameRGB.linesize[0]` should be 3072 = 1024x3; but you posted scaled images, so it's hard to tell what really happens here.

Comment: @Alex Cohn Ive updated the size 1018 and I posted the new result. Why should I multiply by 3 for the line size in RGBA? It's *3 for RGB and *4 for RGBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem here was that I was not using the correct buffer size to write to the file.

```
fwrite(avFrameRGB.data[0], 1, video_dst_bufsize, video_dst_file);
```

The variable video_dst_file was being taken from the return value of

```
video_dst_bufsize = av_image_alloc(yuvframe.data, yuvframe.linesize, destX, destY, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 1);
```

The solution is to get the return value from and use this in the fwrite statement:

```
video_dst_bufsize_RGB = av_image_alloc(avFrameRGB.data, avFrameRGB.linesize, destX, destY, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR32, 1);

fwrite(avFrameRGB.data[0], 1, video_dst_bufsize_RGB, video_dst_file);
```